# WAMP - how to enable "http://" prefix

Tags: wamp

How to enable "http://" prefix in WAMPSERVER (v. 3.0.6)? 
When I enter WAMP home in browser it goes to:

```
localhost
```

I want to have:

```
http://localhost
```

it is came out that some .htaccess conditions are sensitive with that prefix.

Answer (score 0):

it is http://, same thing. you have nothing to fix